# System Event ID 9 pointing to \Device\Scsi\fttxr5_O1 happens at the same time daily

Tags: timeout, raid-controller

OS: Windows 2003
Roles: Exchange Server, Primary DNS Server
Device: Promise TX4310

The problem:
*Almost* every day for the last couple of months at around 8:00 PM (no earlier than 8:02, no later than 8:08) and again at around 2:30 AM a series of 3 or 4 of the following events happens:

```
The description for Event ID ( 9 ) in Source ( fttxr5_O ) could not be found. It contains the following insertion string(s): .
\Device\Scsi\fttxr5_O1
```

According to [KB154690](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154690) Error 9 is

> Description: The device,
>   \Device\ScsiPort0, did not respond
>   within the timeout period.

I know it's either a big file operation happening at the time of the errors or the drives/controller/cables are bad.  I've looked through the event logs to see what might be going on at the same time every day, and there's nothing consistent.  There are backups that happen on the server every other day starting at 11:00 PM, but not every day. No one is in the office after 7:00 PM and before 7:00 AM (verified through the logs).  There are no scheduled events that happen before the times in question.

At this point I'm running out of ideas on how to isolate the issue.  Any help/insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the Exchange mailbox management schedule and the mailbox and public folder database maintenance schedules?

Comment: Mailbox management is set to never run, but the mailbox and public folder database maintenance schedule is set to run from 2:00 AM to 6:00 AM daily.  So that might explain the 2:00 AM errors.  I changed it to run from 12:00 to 4:00 tomorrow morning so I'll see what happens tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the event errors were due to a redundancy error in the RAID 1 array.  I'm still not 100% sure of the operation being done that caused the events to pop up, but whatever's happening, it's trying to write to a bad part of the mirror.